# NGINX shows "bad gateway" when upstream server restart and not back to normal

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

Every time when I'm restart the upstream server, my NGINX shows "bad gateway" which is ok, but later, when the upstream server restarts nginx not recover automatically and I need to restart it (the nginx) manually.

Is there an option to make nginx to check every few seconds if the upstream backed to normal?

```
    upstream core {

    server core:3001;
}

server {
    server_name core.mydomain.com corestg.mydomain.com www.core.mydomain.com;

    #listen 80;
    #listen [::]:80;

    gzip on;
    gzip_static on;    
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript;
    gzip_proxied  any;
    #gzip_vary on;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;    
     listen 443 ssl http2;
     listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
    resolver_timeout 5s;

    server_tokens off;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/domain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/domain.rsa; 

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    location / {
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
        proxy_pass http://core;
        proxy_buffers 8 24k;
        proxy_buffer_size 2k;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_ignore_headers X-Accel-Expires Expires Cache-Control;
        proxy_ignore_headers Set-Cookie;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
#       proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure. NGINX should always perform an so called active health check. Are you able to share the current NGINX config? That will defently help.

Comment: @TimoStark - I updated the questions - hope to hear from you

Comment: So what is core:3001? Is "core" in your /etc/hosts? Is it 127.0.0.1? Why do you have a `resolver`? What external DNS do you have to resolve? Why do you have `        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;` for an http upstream? I have a setup on my NGINX and the passive healthcheck is working.

Comment: Curious: are you running nginx and your upstream in docker containers?  I just hit an issue where a restarted "upstream" container comes back up on a different IP address, and nginx continues to try proxy the old IP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems that NGINX does not do the auto recovery by default.
Changing the config part from:

```
upstream core {
    server core:3001;
}
```

to:

```
{
    server core:3001  max_fails=1 fail_timeout=1s;
    server core:3001  max_fails=1 fail_timeout=1s;
}
```

did the trick. the duplication is not mistake. Nginx tries to resolve the first line, on failure it will try the second one (circularly).

Answer (score 0):

My setup to test NGINX:

Docker-Container simulating the backend exposing port 9002.

```
afd9551abc54   nginx            "/docker-entrypoint.…"   About a minute ago   Up 11 seconds   0.0.0.0:9002->80/tcp                          laughing_pike
```

NGINX configuration

```
# Defined upstream block.
upstream backend {
   server 127.0.0.1:9002;
}

#Main Server block
server {
  listen 80;

  location / {
    proxy_pass       http://backend;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
  }

}
```

Stopping the container will result in 502 Bad Gateway. Starting the container without restarting / reloading NGINX sends the data to the upstream server. So basically that should just work!